# cant send specific command with StreamWriter but when enter command manually its working

Tags: c#, memory, dump, streamwriter

I built a program that dump memory and i'm using an open source tool called "dumpty" to make strings of the dumped memory

["dumpty" tool github](https://github.com/jcdickinson/dumpty)

when I open a command line use the tool and write those four commands:

1. cd dumpty_folder_root
2. dumpty -e repl
3. load "dumped file name.dmp"
4. dumpstrings strings

it works fine and I get new folder with the strings

but when I send the command via StreamWriter it isn't working here you can see the code I use:

```
dumptyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
dumptyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
dumptyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
dumptyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe");
dumptyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
dumptyProcess.Start();

//Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default;

StreamWriter wr = dumptyProcess.StandardInput;

string str = "load \""+dumpFilePath;

//StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(dumptyProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream, encoding);

wr.WriteLine("cd " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
wr.WriteLine("dumpty -e repl");
wr.WriteLine(str);
wr.WriteLine("dumpstrings strings");
wr.Flush();
richTextBox_info.Text += "Running strings on dump file...\n";
```

I know that when I use StreamWriter **all command working except the third command** that load the dump file but i don't know why (again if i do it manually it works) i know all command are working because it creates the strings folder but no strings inside

things i tried:
1. changing the dump file name without spaces and change the command without quotes
2. try changing the encoding of the dumptyProcess
3. copy every command that I enter when using manually cmd to see if they work (they did)

for some reason I cant load the dump file please help

Comment: Is it because your load str doesn't have the ending quote? e.g. `string str = "load \"" + dumpFilePath + "\""` ?

Comment: nope, I found out that I can use only one quote manually and tested it same result still isn't working.....